# Required openjdk6-jre RPM for redhat 64

Tags: linux, redhat

I am looking for openjdk6-jre rpm for redhat 64bit.

I followed [the instructions](http://openjdk.java.net/install/)

But when I try I am getting the below error:

```
[root@DCTXVM20 hita]# su -c "yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk"  
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-5&arch=x86_64 error was   
[Errno 4] IOError: <urlopen error (101, 'Network is unreachable')>               

Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
```

Any pointers where I can find the above rpm?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
yum clean all

If that doesn't work, look here:

> http://www.pubbs.net/200907/fedora/63700-yum-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-for-epel.html
>
> rpm --erase epel-release
>
> and in case you don't have an
>   epel-release package installed (it's
>   included within Fedora 11 by
>   accident), simply delete the epel.repo
>   file.
>
> EPEL is a repository for RHEL and/or
>   CentOS.

PS:
You really want to get "yum" working correctly.

But as a "Plan B" for getting the JDK, you can always try http://www.rpmfind.org